# System shall not include any frameset

Tags: html, frames

I have a very tricky assignment. There is a webpage that uses frameset. I has three framesets one on top which is a banner, one on the left which is a menu bar. When selection is made through menu bar it opens up a 3rd frameset on the right of the menu bar according to whatever is selected from the menu. My question is what is the best way to get rid of frameset? Ways i thought:
-dont use scrollbar in the frameset in middle so that it does not cause all the problem with frameset.

Beside that i can not figure out how to combine all this in a single page as the content on the middle of the page is being fetch from outside app according to what you select on the left menu's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume that you have test.asp page which has 3 frames.
Now do one thing make link in left frame page so it will call like this 
test.asp?menuid=1 
test.asp?menuid=2

and on right frame page do code which get the value of query string "menuid" and bind submenu as per that Menuid.

Thanks
JJ